# Integrating Authorize.net payment gateway to React Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authorize.net

I am trying to integrate Authorize.net payment gateway into my React e-commerce project but I am stuck. I am using the React AcceptJS library and using my own custom form rather than the AcceptJS hosted form.

Using my custom form, I received a payment nonce on the frontend when I dispatch my data to the AcceptJS library but I am not entirely sure how to handle the createTransactionRequest API follow up call as available in documentation. Do I need to set up the payment processing on my backend server (after payment nonce is generated) or the payment processing can out-rightly be handled on Frontend without outsourcing it to the backend server (I am using NodeJS for my backend)?

This is my first project and I've never had to work with any payment gateways before so it is a little bit confusing for me.

[image]

Comment: All payment related "Stuff" should be handled by the backend. As a general note you have to treat front end as hostile environment, because a user can check the source code, find you payment api key in plain text, he could intercept the outgoing call with any kind of MITM soft as Burp Suite, and alter pricing or do any other unknown damage. You should take in the order from the front, collect only Ids of products, all the rest of the payment info should come from backend, backend should produce the final price and so on.